# How to find the difference between two numbers in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to find the difference between two numbers in anuglar js directive tags.

```
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
    {{post.upvotes}}
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"
      ng-click="incrementDownvotes(post)"></span>
    {{post.downvotes}}


    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon-minus"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon-plus"></span>
      {{post.upvotes - post.downvotes}}  // I want the difference of these two numbers
```

There has to be a way to do this using the absolute value of the two numbers, or using some angular method to find the difference between them.  Currently with the above code it will execute the equation, but it does strict subtraction, not giving me the actual difference between these numbers.

Comment: create a function associated to your `post` model and call it...? (as oppsed to doing the math inline)

Comment: what do you mean by "strict subtraction", and what's the diff? subtracting one number from another yields the difference, unless i'm worse at math than even i thought...

Comment: @dandavis he means that he wants a difference between the absolute values, but angular is just doing regular signed-subtraction.

Comment: use Math.abs(n) to turn any number into the positive version

Comment: So you are saying to put something like FindDifference({{post.upvotes, post.downvotes}}) and then that function would execute for each iteration through the ng-repeat directive?  @ochi

Comment: @javascriptJenkins I added an answer based on my understanding of your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like this to your `post` definition (in the model)

```
...
// assuming you have these already (or similar)
post.upvotes = 2;
post.downvotes = 1;
...
// add something along the lines of
post.voteDiff = function(){
  return Math.abs(upvotes - downvotes);  // would return 1 in this case
}
```

Then in your HTML could would simply call it like any other attribute `{{post.voteDiff()}}`

**UPDATED**

Thanks to @New Dev for the correction in the comments

Comment: you meant to say: `{{post.voteDiff()}}` - i.e. actually invoking the function

Comment: You could also modify  {{post.upvotes - post.downvotes}} to  {{abs(post.upvotes - post.downvotes)}}

Comment: I just realized I was thinking about this way too hard.  If I just add the two numbers together I get what I am looking for.  Upvotes will never be negative and downvotes will never be positive so adding them together will always give the difference....

Answer (score 0):

```
{{post.upvotes + post.downvotes}}
```

This solved the problem.  Don't need any fancy math or methods.